# Visio shape deforms / explodes automatically when shapes connect to each other

Tags: forms, visio

i have big issues with Microsoft Visio Professional 2016, where i use walls to create our garden plan. Now i have the issue, that somewhen, when i place walls close to each other, they extend to fill the 'missing' corner. But this behaviour is not intended from me. In fact, this feature is completely destroying my plan, as both the pictures below show.

I already have completely disabled 'Visual support' as well as all of the subsequent features like 'order', 'glue', 'dynamic gitter', 'drawing support'. Also i have disabled all options below File > Options > Extended > such as 'Activate Livedynamic' and else.

I don't know how to describe it, it is something like it would explode but it is due to this automatic shape connection. Can anyone tell me, which feature to enable / disable that this behaviour stops and the walls do not extend automatically?

Please help me out, i spent hours with this.

Thanks a lot in advance
Patrick

[image: shape io]
[image: Shape nio]
[image: Options]
[image: Visual support]
[image: Visual support detail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disable **Automation events**
File -> Options -> Advanced -> Enable Automation events (uncheck)
[image: Visio Options window]

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the hint, really appreciate it!